# Passport-azure-ad : authentication failed due to: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 3128

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, passport.js, passport-azure-ad

I try to implement Passport-azure-ad OIDCStrategy on my node application.
It is working find in my personal computer but with my corporate laptop (without VPN or proxy configured) I cannot connect and I get that error :

```
authentication failed due to: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 3128
```

I don't understand why because I can access by a browser to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/` without any issues.

I don't understand what endpoint node try to contact and why the tunnel socket cannot be established.

Any help ?

Thanks